# Using SQL to replace a value across all tables / entries

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I recently migrated a WordPress web site, before migrating it I re-created the site by exporting / importing the data in phpMyAdmin

the issue I am running into is the old domain seems to be causing issues and I'm guessing it's on a database level. When I do a search in the database there's plenty of references to the old web site.

I am thinking the best way to overcome this is to replace the old URL, with the new URL.

Is there a method or script I can use that will replace all values across my database, regardless of which table / name it's in?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Look to the `REPLACE` function.

Comment: This sounds like a task for dynamic sql; you'd need to query the system tables or `information_schema` and build a list of candidate tables, dynamically constructing and executing update statements. Specifics will vary depending on your specific RDBMS.